# What this ("board[y][x].cell") method means?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom-events

This is the website of a JavaScript tutorial I'm trying to learn ([Snake In JavaScript](https://hjnilsson.com/2018/04/19/snake-in-pure-html-part-2/))

It's a snake game with JavaScript but there are some things I don't understand:

1. What is `board[][]`?
2. Why do they add a `.snake` custom method after the above one ? Why is its value equal to 1?
3. How does the snake move?  (In other words, how does the loop work for the array to add cells in y and x axis according to key press?)

These are some obstacles in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer in question 1 by 1:

1. `Board[][]` mean multi-dimension array (2 in this case) - in the case of the snake game it represent the board where each row is array and the first column is array of arrays
2. The `.snake` is not a method but an Boolean variable in the cell object which indicate if the snake is present in that specific cell - it has value of one if the snake is there and 0 otherwise. This var used where we display the board on screen.
3. The `enterKey` function is called whenever key is stroke. Then by the key we specify the snake direction and change the head coordinate accordingly.

As for your question in the title: the `.cell` is a object that is the base object of the board - each element in the 2-dimensional array is a dictionary name `cell`.
I hope this make it little but clearer

Comment: I got it well, but what about snake Movement. How its cell move one by one after each other when it direction change

Comment: @AnmolKashyap The `snakeDirection` changed in every key-stroke. If the key does not pressed the direction remain the same. Notice that the snake not actually moving, the base of the snake stays in the starting position and only the head advances. So once we set cell as "snake" it remain as it till the end.